# Information matrix from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
    Customer Id  year
0       1510220024  2017
1       1510270013  2017
2       1511160047  2017
3       1512100014  2017
4       1603180006  2017
5       1605030030  2017
6       1605160013  2017
7       1606060008  2017
8       1510220024  2018
9       1606270014  2017
10      1608080011  2017
11      1608090002  2017
12      1511160047  2018
13      1606270014  2018
```

And I want to build the following matrix from the above dataframe:

```
     2017 2018
2017  11   3
2018   3   3
```

This matrix tells that there were total 11 customers in year 2017 and three of them also appeared in 2018 and so on. In actual, I have 7 years of data so it would be 7x7 matrix. I am struggling for a while now but can't get this right.

Comment: Can you explain second column, `[3,3]` ?

Comment: 3 in first row means that out of 11 customers that appeared in 2017, 3 also appeared in 2018 and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`merge` + `crosstab`:

```
m = df.merge(df, left_on='Customer Id', right_on='Customer Id')
pd.crosstab(m.year_x, m.year_y)
```

```
year_y  2017  2018
year_x
2017      11     3
2018       3     3
```